# Check if user is Windows authenticated in .net Core 2.2

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have developed a .net core 2.2 MVC application that allows both anonymous and Windows authenticated access.  I don't want to ask users to log in to their windows account but do need to know if they're already logged in.

For example, I am currently authenticated in my browser. If I go to a controller method that is not decorated with the "[Authorize]" attribute, the HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.  If I decorate that same controller method with the "[Authorize]" attribute, it does not prompt me to enter my credentials and my identity information is populated in the HttpContext.User.Identity property and the "IsAuthenticated" of that object property is true.

How can I get the HttpContext.User.Identity property populated with the windows user details IF they are authenticated but not trigger the login popup (by using ChallengeAsync or decorating my controller with an "[Authorize]" attribute) if they are not.

Please be kind - identity, authentication, authorization - this stuff is my kryptonite and I really don't understand why! :-)  Thank you!

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce the issue ? Fail to reproduce your issue with [TestWindowsAuth](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/ET2zXIU5rqFIhilV8p5GyxIB4_MnTsySmobCsafMobDGUw?e=2eYQJd) .

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I just created a brand new web application and configured it to use Windows authentication from the start.  The Identity property is populated as I was hoping, so this tells me I have a configuration problem.  I'll do a comparison between the two projects and see what I've done wrong.  Thank you!